# Octave cannot find file even in correct path

Tags: windows, window, octave, gnu

I am writing a simple octave program, but I cannot run it through octave-cli
I have put octave in environment variable, but it still cannot run it
Here are the commands I type in the octave-cli, it show that I do not have a file name 'question1.m', but with the `ls` command, it shows me it have the file in the path.

```
GNU Octave, version 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 The Octave Project Developers.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-w64-mingw32".

Additional information about Octave is available at https://www.octave.org/.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit https://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read https://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

octave:1> pwd
ans = C:\Users\6720\OneDrive?﹝\GitHub\octave-lab\lab03
octave:2> ls
 磁碟區 C 中的磁碟沒有標籤。
 磁碟區序號:  76E5-73EB

 C:\Users\6720\OneDrive文档\GitHub\octave-lab\lab03 的目錄

[.]             .gitignore      ie-lab-3.pdf    IE_Encode.m     IE_Sampling.m   question2.m     s3.m
[..]            demo.wav        IE_Decode.m     IE_Quant.m      question1.m     s2.m
              11 個檔案       1,887,210 位元組
               2 個目錄  76,459,147,264 位元組可用
octave:3> question1
error: no such file, 'C:\Users\6720\OneDrive??\GitHub\octave-lab\lab03\question1.m'
octave:4>
```

Here is my program code:

```
# question1.m
[x, fs] = audioread('demo.wav');
m = IE_Sampling(x, fs, 4000);
m = IE_Sampling(x, fs, 80000);
# When M = 4
M = 4;
[s, lv] =IE_Quant(m, M);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(s,"b;s[n];",m,"k;m[n];")
xlim([0,1000])
title("s[n] and m[n] with M = 4")
# When M = 8
M = 8;
[s, lv] =IE_Quant(m, M);
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(s,"b;s[n];",m,"k;m[n];")
xlim([0,1000])
title("s[n] and m[n] with M = 8")
# When M = 16
M = 16;
[s, lv] =IE_Quant(m, M);
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(s,"b;s[n];",m,"k;m[n];")
xlim([0,1000])
title("s[n] and m[n] with M = 16")
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Try to remove all Chinese characters from your path name. It looks like that is what is tripping up Octave. Octave uses UTF-8, like all sane software should, but Windows is built around UTF-16, and doesn’t always properly deal with UTF-8. So this issue would be a problem in the interaction between Octave and Windows, when dealing with non-ASCII characters in file path names.

Comment: problem fixed ty.

Comment: Also please report this as a bug to the Octave maintainers at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave. They are actively trying to fix this Unicode filesystem stuff.